# Calculate GPU energy when running a python script

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I am trying to calculate the energy usage of a GPU for different Python (TensorFlow) scripts. The way I do it is that I use `t_start = time.process_time()` and `t_final = time.process_time()` to measure the execution time. Then I multiply this time by the average power consumption of the GPU from `nvidia-smi`. Is that correct? Are there other ways to do so?

Comment: Process_time will get the number of fractional seconds that a process executed, and average power consumption is given in watts. Multiplying watts by seconds yields joules, which is the SI unit of energy. This seems like it checks out. What specific problem are you trying to address that you are running in to?

Comment: I am not running into problems. I just wanted to know if what I am doing is acceptable and check whether there is a more accurate way.